# Web hosting company basically forces me to use their domain name

Tags: web-hosting, domains

I've recently stumbled upon an unusual problem with one of hosting companies called 
giga-international.com. Anyway, I've ordered com.hr domain from Croatian domain name registration company, and my client insisted on using this host provider as couple of his friends already are hosted with them.

I thought something was fishy when the first result on Google for Giga International was [this](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1945018) little forum rant instead of their webpage. When I was checking their services they listed many features etc... space available, bandwidth etc. I just wanted to check how much ram do I get for my PHP scripts so I emailed them, and they told me that was company secret. Seriously?

Anyway, since my client still insisted on hosting with them I've bought their Webspace package. During registration I **had** to choose free domain name because I couldn't advance registration without it. Nowhere was said, not even in general terms and conditions that I wouldn't be able to change that domain name.  At least not for double the price of domain name per year.

They said I can either move my domain name over to them (and pay them domain registration), or pay them 1 Euro per month for managing a DNS entry.

On any previous hosting solution I was able to manage my domain names just by pointing my domain to their name servers, and this is something completely new and absurd for me. They also said that usual approach is not possible because of security and hardware limitations.

I'd like to know what you guys think about this case, and should I report, and where should I report this case.

**In short. They forced me to register free domain name which doesn't suit my needs in order to register for their webspace package, and refuse to change domain name for my account until I either transfer domain to them or pay them DNS management which costs double the price of the domain name per year.**

Comment: If you client wants to use them, have them pay for it, why do you care they want to use a bad hosting company.  What is there to important exactly?  **They are not forcing you to be their customer.** just increase your costs to cover the difference.  It sounds like they are a budget hosting company.

Comment: Unfortunately, my client is a*hole + we allready have set contract with fixed prices so this'll go of my budget and also he says he don't want to pay aditional money for DNS management.

Comment: Any decent web developer/consultant would care if their client were being ripped off by their web host. This web host is clearly incredibly shady and unprofessional, but unfortunately it's not illegal. This is why organizations like the Better Business Bureau were formed. Short of reporting them to such consumer protection organizations (the effectiveness of which depends on local culture--how socially aware and conscious of consumer rights the business community is), you can only tell your client how wrong this situation is and urge them to change web hosts.

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to rework your standard contract in the future to avoid being cornered by a bad client like this. Always create a clause in the contract that allows you to renegotiate pricing if external expenses exceed the projections of your original estimate, allowing you to pass on external costs to the client if they choose to go with a service provider against your recommendations.

Comment: Also, never call your client an a*hole publicly. This could backfire.

Comment: Don't most web hosting companies allow you to use your own domain if you have one? Well at least most reputable hosting companies would give you the option to register a new domain when you signup for their services or bring your own.

Comment: Yes they do, that's why I was so suprised to find out this one doesn't.

Comment: These companies hinge on oversold ad-paid web call-card pages. They don't have the infrastructure to support a medium to big website. They will terminate you if your site gets any reasonable traffic, like over 1GB/mo. You need to find a real hosting. And never buy the domain from the same company. Make sure that the one who you bought the domain from fills in YOUR name in the national registry, or else they could extort you in the future.